# How do you insert into mongoDB float data type in Perl?

Tags: perl, mongodb

I tried to convert a string "200.991" to float but unfortunately perl interpret value as a string not as float type

With Data::Types module by

`my $float=to_float(200.991", 2)`

and with the following coammnd

`my $float =sprintf('%.2f', '200.991')`

finally if I insert string to mongodb like

`$collection->insert({  High_Rate   =>  $float });`

mongodb store value as string

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("533143e63bb2cce912000009"), "High_Rate" : "200.99" }`

any ideas how could I save issue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect

```
$collection->insert({ High_Rate => 0+$float });
```

will do the trick (that's how to coerce strings to numbers for JSON values).